# Extract keywords from Excel or Google spreadsheet column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of interview responses and want to extract keywords(from a defined list of keywords) and list them(delimited by commas) in a column next to the interview questions. See image for reference.

Can I use a formula? or VBA? or a google sheets script/add-on?

Thank you for your help!
[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: You can loop through the keyword array and search each question for each keyword.  A simple approach is to paste the found keywords into each subsequent column of the row and concatenate the list into one cell, delimited by commas; I feel that is simpler than storing the found values as variables, then pasting them after finishing the search in a comma-delimited string, from a coding standpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$8:$A$11,A1)),$A$8:$A$11,""))
```

As an Array formula.  It needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you do not have access to TEXTJOIN() in your Excel, Put this in a module and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

---

In Google Sheets:

```
=Join(",",filter($A$8:$A$11,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$8:$A$11,A1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. I used the Google Sheets version and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What would this look like as an Array Formula @ScottCraner.
So that I only have to paste the formula into one cell (B2)and it autopopulates down.

Comment: Don't think you can do that, but ask a new question, maybe some on is smarter than me. @herteladrian

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet!
Anyway, I think I found exactly what you're looking for. In your example, you'll want something like

```
    =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*startup*",A1,1)),"","startup, ")
```

and to put that in your output cell.

[Source](http://ccm.net/forum/affich-46323-find-word-within-cell-put-value-in-adjacent)

Edit: I saw after I posted this that Scott beat me by 3 minutes. However, they're slightly different ways to do it so I'll leave mine up as well.

Comment: This doesn't seems like it does what I need. Your code looks like it requires me to hardcode each keyword. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's a bit barbaric, but if you only have the 4 keywords you posted it should be fine. Much more than that, however, and this pales even more in comparison to Scott's answer! I left mine in as a proof of concept thing after I saw his answer. I tested it with some dummy data in Excel and it printed out what (I think) you were asking in your question - a list of words that were in the cell from the given list. For more than a few keywords, Scott's is definitely the better option though!